# Changing GUI library : QT, wxPython... anything else?

Tags: python, wxpython, pyqt

Actually working on a project in python with PyQT, we choose to create widgets that were "unpleasant" or that didn't have a good enough behaviour.

So, we finally found that QToolbox, QDate and some others had a behaviour non acceptable for the project, so we had to adapt these.

We had also to create a complete new widget : A scheduler.

As we were creating these, it has been decided that it took too much time. So we were asked to think about other libraries.

I actually found a project of a scheduler in wxPython, that actually looks like what we want ( but we believe that we'll have to adapt it a lot ). Here it is : http://code.google.com/p/wxscheduler/

So, I ask everyone that have some more experience than me in GUI programming in python : Do we need to start again the project in anything other than PyQT? I know the question is weird, but what you need to know is :

- The project has now been going on for 2 months
- I know only PyQT, and started working in python 2 month ago
- We are currently 3 in the project, and we currently know only PyQT
- We have currently managed a lot of the PyQT widgets, and were starting to code these new widgets.

Please help us =)

Thanks

Edit : I should have add that the project is opensource and multi-platform

Answer (score 2):

Feel free to look at other libraries if you like. Robin Dunn, the creator of wxPython, recently started working on PySide and he found it somewhat similar to wx, so you might find that wxPython will fit your brain fairly well too. I certainly think wx's class names are more intuitive than PyQt's. The only way to know for certain is to actually experiment a little and see if it works. I will say that the wxPython community is one of the best Python communities I've dealt with over the years.

Comment: After some research, I can't really see ( on the paper ) which one is the best, and this is actually completely normal, as we all have different needs.

As PyQT was really good for 95% of the widgets, we were told that we couldn't spend more time on the 5%... What we are afraid, is that we spend really too much time on learning and re-create all the UI, which has been decided to be done first ( don't ask me why... )

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use an HTML scheduler control via QtWebKit. If your UI can accommodate a QWebView in the place where you'd otherwise have a custom scheduler widget, there are probably a number of excellent scheduler widgets (implemented as jQuery plugins, etc.) you could choose from.

Comment: How would the hmtl/javascript scheduler interact with other Qt elements then ?

Comment: Yeah, actually we thought about that and consider it... But we actually don't know if it would be possible to connect it to the database, that'll be manage in Python...

Comment: It's fairly straightforward to make an HTML/JavaScript widget running inside a web view interact with Qt elements/code (and thus connect to data/code in Python).    
  
See:  
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkit/qtwebkit-bridge.html  
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkit/qwebframe.html#addToJavaScriptWindowObject  
http://qt-project.org/wiki/Server-Driven_UI_with_Hybrid_QtWebkit

Answer (score -1):

> we choose to create widgets that were "unpleasant" or that didn't have
>   a good enough behaviour.

Why don't you create "pleasant" widgets ?

> so we had to adapt these.

Yes. It is the solution.

> it has been decided that it took too much time

Don't you think it would take much more time if you change the whole GUI API ?
As for i know, there is not such native Scheduler in any Python GUI library, especially one you could use with Qt. I don't think it would be so long to recreate one, unless you have very specific needs, that would confirm you wouldn't find a such existing thing in an existing library.
Concerning wxScheduler, i guess you can have a look to the code, even it uses wxWidget and you're working with Qt, to get an idea how to do it.

Comment: This is my advice too, but we need to think about it so that's why I asked here.

I think it would take much more time if we started again with another library, but maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: That's what i meant too. Imho, the best thing you have to do is customizing what's brought with Qt. There are many way to do so with Qt events or by constructing more complex structures based on simple widgets. Unless you want something that you absolutely can't recreate with Qt, don't change the graphic library, especially if your project is mainly based on it.

Comment: """I think it would take much more time if we started again with another library"""  That probably depends more on how your current code is organized.  If your application code is tightly integrated with your UI code then yes, it will probably take a long time to port.  If you've kept them fairly well separated then it may not be too hard to replace the UI.  As for porting custom widgets, the hard part is already done, all the trial and error on look and feel and events, etc. Using what you've already learned about that and using it with a new toolkit not too bad.

Comment: Concretely, what wxPython (or some other toolkit) can provide more than PyQT, especially if developers only know PyQT. Don't you think that it would be a waste of time to definitely change the program toolkit just to manage a scheduler that can be recreated in a few weeks. By the way, in which extent the behaviour of the QT element is not acceptable for your project ?

Comment: I don't really want to change the UI library, but we were asked to search for new one. I think we can perfectly manage the minor troubles with PyQT that we had. What I asked for is : is there any special widget or maybe... easiness in creation of widget like a scheduler or a Date line edit that could spare us some time, but I'm afraid I already know the answer...

And btw, the UI code is completely separated ( except maybe signals ) from the code but that's nearly all we have today...